# Android section 4.4 violation How to stop webView activity/return to menu

Tags: android

I have an app that streams live audio, but also has a webView that allows users to navigate to our website (from within the App).

The live stream will continue to play regardless of whether the app is the active screen or not, which is the desired behaviour (and we have other apps taht do this that have not been rejected).

On one of our apps, the website (via the webView) can access a YouTube video and my understanding is that this particular app has fallen foul of Google Plays 4.4 (Your app is violating our policy because it enables the user to play YouTube content in the background while the app is not active (meaning all playback should stop, once the user closes the app, including pressing the "power" button) because if, for example, you press the power button to turn off the screen, the YouTube video continues to play in the background.

My understanding is that the rejection is due to this behaviour (YouTube video is allowed to continue to play) rather than the app itself continuing to stream the live audio).

On this basis, how could I detect if the power button is pressed, or if the screen sleeps, to switch away from the webView, say, back to the home screen?

From the app launch, you get presented with a menu and can choose the webView from one of the menu buttons, which opens within the App. The desired solution here would be that it the home or power button are pressed (or the devices turns the screen off), the webview would close and return to the main menu.

I'm not necessarily after code (though that would be appreciated!) but I am after advice/confirmation that this is the likely cause of the rejection my idea is the correct one to overcome/comply with the terms set by Google.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE : I'm using this code in HomeActivity. The `VOLUME_UP`, `VOLUME_DOWN` and `KEYCODE_BACK` all perform as expected, but the `KEYCODE_POWER` does not, my desired effect is for it to go back (using the `onBackPressed();`) but it just turns the screen off and the video continues to play in the background

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER:
                onBackPressed();
                onPause();
                return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

I have also put an Log.i for each button, they all log a key press except the power button. In the log, when I hit power, I get this:

```
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 1782547095
D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=46202}]
V/FA: Using measurement service
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Update:

I put this in the onPause(), which has resolved the issue for me, it is probably a workaround, as what it does is it causes the webview to reload the page, thus stopping the vYouTube video in the webview and the app has actually just been approved BUT, it now crashes on exit with the following, which is a direct result of the code I added (if i take it out, the crash stops):

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Webservice.getInstance().activity = "listen";
        WebviewActivity webviewActivity=new WebviewActivity();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("type","web");
        bundle.putString("url","http://www.website.com");
        webviewActivity.setArguments(bundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,webviewActivity,"WebviewActivity").commit();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Above it what it has now (stops video, but crashes). It originally had this (didn't stop video, but no crash):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Webservice.getInstance().activity = "listen";
}
```

The crash log is this:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.auto.packagename, PID: 10484
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@169b874[] not attached to window manager
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:473)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:382)
                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:124)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:357)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:340)
                      at com.soft.network.fragments.WebviewActivity$2.onProgressChanged(WebviewActivity.java:67)
                      at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap.onProgressChanged(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:45)
                      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:79)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6464)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
D/LOG: Asking for stream handler for protocol: 'https'
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5A68B5D20084-0001-28F4-4DB370E6A585
Application terminated.
```

Update (inside WebviewActivity.java)

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                if(progress == 100)
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

There is also a onProgressChanged in HomeActivity.java, but it is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use these mehtods:
`OnBackPressed()` if the user pressed back button

`OnDestroy()` it called before the activity is destroyed

`OnStop()` the activity is no longer visible

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the onBackPressed() already, which works for the back button, but not for the power button. See edited above. I have added the same code for POWER_DOWN but it doesn't work, it just turns the screen off with the video still playing in the background (which I understand is what Google have the issue with). I'll update with the code in a moment.

Comment: Did you use OnPause method also ?

Comment: Thank you, I have also added that, see edit above, but still the same. All buttons work, except KEYCODE_POWER which just turns the screen off, does not stop what is happening in the webView. I need this button to perform the same as the 'back' button (as well as turn the screen off).

Comment: I see my error, I needed to include the commands I needed into the protected void onPause() section. I've now been able to resolve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmmm. All is not good... I have been able to resolve, I will post above what I have done, but now the App crashed when I exit with the messages I'll post also. Any ideas why? 2 secs, let me post in the original question... Thanks.

Comment: Yes please post the code and the error messages to be able to help you.

Comment: Added, thank you for your help here, much appreciated

Comment: Your error is in onProgressChanged method. I guess you are trying to finish the activity without closing a dialog. please if you can post onProgressChanged code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163817/discussion-between-elmaravilla-and-omega1).